# Raspberry Pi and read/write on NTFS with Raspbian 5/5/2015

Tags: raspbian, mount

I haven't stumbled across many recent articles or websites explaining how to get Raspberry Pi with Raspbian 5/5/2015 (and presumably later) working with an NTFS volume/drive.

- What is the default behavior of Raspbian?
- What packages do you need?
- Are there post-package installation scripts, actions, or commands that must be run, created, or modified?
- Do you only get read/write in the terminal?  Or do you get it in File Manager too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Raspbian 5/5/2015, the version I am working with, comes with read support for NTFS.  Presumably earlier versions over the past year or two probably have this as well, but much past 2 years, I don't think they do.

On a default install of Raspbian, the OS will automount your NTFS drive as read-only to /media with the NTFS volume name as a folder name.  This makes things easy to see, find, and understand. eEpecially if you're primarily a Windows user or new to Linux.

To get read and write access, you have to install some software, in this case, just 1 package: ntfs-3g.  Some older instructions may tell you to use ntfsprogs, but there's no need for that.  To find out the difference, see this page/article/question: [Which package to use for NTFS? NTFS-3G, NTFSPROGS? [closed]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33367/which-package-to-use-for-ntfs-ntfs-3g-ntfsprogs)  There are no answers, but the comments are good.

Before you install ntfs-3g, you'll need to update apt-get.  You can do that with this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm not sure why, but the package links for apt-get are out of date in regards to ntfs-3g.  Once you update apt-get, then you can install ntfs-3g:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Then you will need to power cycle the Raspberry Pi.  [I'm not yet sure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/raspbian-5-5-2015-will-automount-on-cold-boot-and-plugin-but-not-reboot-is-tha) why there is a difference between a reboot and a power cycle, but you **must** power cycle the Raspberry Pi.  That means turn it off, wait 5+ seconds, then turn it back on.  Since my drive was powered by the same [USB hub-thingey](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Onn-4-Port-USB-Power-Hub-for-Home/36854850) as my Pi, I used the switch to turn off the Pi and the drive, waited 5 seconds, and then turned both of them back on.

That's all you need to do!

To test, in the GUI, I opened up File Manager, saw that the drive was mounted in /media, and created a new directory somewhere.  It succeeded.  If you had tried to do that before all of this, then that would have failed with an error message about insufficient privileges.

Comment: Apparently jessie now has the NTFS 3g driver. See [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38723/ntfs-usb-hdd-read-only-how-to-enable-write-permissions)

Comment: Apparently, buster needs this again.  My NTFS drive was read-only, `dpkg -l | grep ntfs-3g` returned nothing, and this answer by itself made it writable.

Answer (score 0):

To get RW access to NTFS drives on Raspbian Buster, all you need to do is to run `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and re-plug the drive. You don't have to reboot, let alone power cycle the RPi.

Comment: Buster is the latest version of the OS, and NTFS support is included and activated by default, and has been for almost 4 years, as evidenced by commentary here.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser It wasn't in the recent Buster image that I've got, and apparently [I'm not alone](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104158/cant-open-mounted-usb-stick-permission-denied).