# Can't open mounted USB stick - Permission denied

Tags: mount, filesystem

I followed this guide to automount a USB stick to my Raspberry Pi 2. I'm using Raspbian Lite.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md

The USB stick is a `Sandisk Cruzer Fit 16GB`.

I created a folder `/media/mydisk`.

I formated the USB stick on my desktop (Windows 10).

I plugged in the stick to the Raspberry Pi, I got the UUID and added this line into `/etc/fstab`.

```
UUID=5C24-1453 /media/mydisk FSTYPE defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail 0 0
```

I changed the FSTYPE to ntfs and the UUID with the UUID I saw on the terminal.
I want NTFS so I can read the USB stick from Windows.

The problem is when I try to access the folder (after mounted the USB stick) `/media/mydisk` I get Permission denied error.

Comment: `sudo apt install ntfs-3g` then `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/mydisk -o uid=pi,gid=pi`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NTFS USB HDD Read-Only - How to enable write permissions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38723/ntfs-usb-hdd-read-only-how-to-enable-write-permissions), [Raspberry Pi and read/write on NTFS with Raspbian 5/5/2015](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/raspberry-pi-and-read-write-on-ntfs-with-raspbian-5-5-2015)

Answer (score 1):

You mount the filesystem with **ntfs**. This driver provides only read-only access according to [Debian NTFS](https://wiki.debian.org/NTFS). You have to install the third generation NTFS device driver with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

and then mount your filesystem with FSTYPE **ntfs-3g**. Then you have read/write access to your mounted device.