# Delete file from external NTFS hard drive

Tags: raspbian, permissions, ntfs

I have an external HDD formatted in NTFS connected to my raspberry.
I need to clear some space on it but, although I have all the permission and pi is the owner of most of the directories, when i execute a rm -rf on a directory this message appear

> rm: can not remove "path": Operation not permitted

this is the situation after a ls -lah

```
totale 559M
drwx------  1 pi   pi    12K lug 25  2016 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4,0K mar 30 21:55 ..
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4,0K giu  1  2016 Develop
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4,0K mag  8  2014 Documenti
-rw-------  2 pi   pi    104 lug 27  2013 .dropbox.device
drwx------  1 pi   pi   136K nov 21 22:06 Video
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4,0K giu  1  2016 Programmi
drwx------  1 pi   pi      0 lug 25  2016 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwx------  1 pi   pi   8,0K nov 21 22:54 Foto
-rw-------  2 pi   pi   444M ago 22  2015 Foto guida.avi
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4,0K lug 18  2015 Foto_guida_IMGS
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4,0K ago 22  2015 System Volume Information
-rw-------  2 pi   pi   115M giu 23  2014 document.pdf
```

and this is the result of a mount command

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=469532k,nr_inodes=117383,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/114 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=94776k,mode=700,uid=114,gid=65534)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=94776k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sda1 on /media/pi/dIVANO2TB type ntfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1,uhelper=udisks2)
```

someone can help me please

Comment: What was the actual command you used?

Comment: For try to delete? rm - rf folderName i have tryed with and without sudo but the result is the same

Comment: Also add the output of your `mount` command (maybe you have mounted read-only?). And please copy-paste the text instead of a screenshot if possible.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev i have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/33626):

I believe you're using the wrong identifier for the NTFS file system in your mount command and that's why it's mounting as *read-only*. First, make sure you have installed the ntfs-3g package by running `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` (to be able to enable *write* access to NTFS volumes). Then modify `ntfs` to `ntfs-3g` in the following line:

`/dev/sda1 on /media/pi/dIVANO2TB type ntfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1,uhelper=udisks2)`

Now reboot your Raspberry Pi and try again.